# Error passing to javascript a string encoded with php's urlencode()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, urlencode, decodeuricomponent

i have a string passed from php script to jquery script encoded with rawurlencode():

```
$str = '<test>';
echo rawurlencode($str);
```

and i'm trying to decode it with decodeURIComponent:

```
var decoded = decodeURIComponent(str);
```

finally i'm getting "%3Ctest%3E" anyway. (I have tried urlencode() with the same result aswell.) What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Why are you urlencoding HTML?

Comment: You don't need to urlencode it. Why are you?

Comment: `decodeURIComponent("%3Ctest%3E");` gives `"<test>"`. You need to show more code, but I'd echo the earlier commenters. Use `json_encode` if you are trying to make a string safe for insertion in a `<script>` element.

Comment: i'm build a table in a php script from mysql requests to put into jquery ui tabs page later

Answer (score 0):

PHP side :

```
$str = htmlentities('<test>');
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($str);
```

Javascript side :

```
var decoded = JSON.parse(answer);
$('#ui-tabs-1').append(decoded);
```

In such a way, you'll be able to pass arrays or objects from PHP to your JS code too.

More info [here](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: `var decoded = JSON.parse(answer);`
`$('#ui-tabs-1').append(decoded);`
shows """". firebug shows response "test".

Comment: hmm, echo json_encode(htmlentities($str)); may work if you want to insert result to the dom.